# SQL query with a loop and two IF

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, while-loop

I have a  sql request  below.
in the table [ServicesConf] there are 2 rows: ID = 1, 2, but after executing sql query to table [ServicesLog] 3 rows are inserted.

How to make only 2 rows be inserted?

```
DECLARE @cnt int = 1
       ,@max int = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [ServicesConf]);

WHILE @cnt <= @max
BEGIN
DECLARE @DateTimeNow datetime = GETDATE()
DECLARE @DateTimeNowTimeHM varchar(5) = FORMAT(@DateTimeNow, 'HH:mm') --CONVERT(varchar(5), GETDATE(),108)
DECLARE @DateTimeNowTimeM varchar(2) = FORMAT(@DateTimeNow, 'mm')
DECLARE @DateTimeNow_WeekDay varchar = (SELECT DATEPART(WEEKDAY,@DateTimeNow))
DECLARE @DateTimeNow_WeekDay_Check int = (SELECT 1 FROM [ServicesConf] WHERE [SCHEDULE_DAY] LIKE '%' + @DateTimeNow_WeekDay + '%' AND [ID] = @cnt)
DECLARE @DateTimeNow_WeekHour_Check int = (SELECT 1 FROM [ServicesConf] WHERE [SCHEDULE_HOUR] = @DateTimeNowTimeHM AND [ID] = @cnt)
DECLARE @DateTimeNow_Repeat_Check int = (SELECT 1 FROM [ServicesConf] WHERE [REPEAT] LIKE '%' + @DateTimeNowTimeM + '%' AND [ID] = @cnt)

    IF (@DateTimeNow_WeekDay_Check = 1
        AND @DateTimeNow_Repeat_Check = 1)
        BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [ServicesLog] ()
        SELECT *
        FROM [ServicesConf]
        WHERE [REPEAT] IS NOT NULL
        END

    IF (@DateTimeNow_WeekDay_Check = 1
        AND @DateTimeNow_WeekHour_Check = 1)
        BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [ServicesLog] ()
        SELECT *
        FROM [ServicesConf]
        WHERE [REPEAT] IS NULL
        END
    SET @cnt = @cnt + 1
END
```

Comment: Why do you want to use a `WHILE` in the first place? SQL is a set based language, it excels at set based methods and performs awfully at iterative ones.

Comment: I don't know your data or what you're trying to achieve, but I have a strong suspicion that the two `INSERT` queries need an extra line in the `WHERE` clause of `AND [ID] = @cnt`. If that's right, there will be other far more efficient ways to achieve the same result.

Comment: Possibly in one of the loop iterations both IFs are true so you get two records in the same iteration. You can use "ELSE" instead of the second "IF" to avoid it